# HttpResponse Date field is getting changed in MVC Client

Tags: json, wcf, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, date

Http response for Date is getting changed on Client side what i have received from the WCF service.

Below is the output I am getting from Service:

I am getting different date for UID(175605)

Here is my Client Code:

From the above response the Date for the following is changed (/Date(1437657709773-0400).

When i tried to convert this new Date(1437657709773-0400),I am getting the date as

"+new Date(1437657709773-0400)-->Thu Jul 23 2015 18:51:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)    Object, (Date)"

which is different which i got it from WCF service response for UID (175605)

Why the Date is changing from Service(2015-07-23T06:45:34.973) to Client(2015-07-23 18:51).

Can you please correct if i am missing any conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd a similar problem facing time zone difference, here is a good link where you can find information about how to solve the problem:

[Coding Best Practices Using DateTime in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx)

Hope it helps.